# Does Google pick up anchor text that is in nested elements?

Tags: seo, anchor

When Google looks at anchor text on a website, will it pickup the text if it is inside nested elements?

So for example:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Visit Google</a>
```

To:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">
    <div class="circle">
        <span>Visit Google</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

The reason I ask is because I want to use css3 elements for certain links on my website, to style them as circles. But the anchor text needs to be picked up for these links, so I want to know wether or not the above is bad practice in this case.

Comment: Regardless of SEO: [Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)

Comment: This is allowed in HTML5, which is what the site in question uses.

Answer (score 1):

It looks perfectly legal to me. If you have a Google Webmaster Tools account, I believe that you can use Labs, Instant Previews and Fetch as Google to see if it is working okay. Create an example somewhere toward the top of a page, use the tools, then compare the results. You can make a fast and temporary change and not worry about the effects in the index/SERPs as long as you Fetch as Google again after you change the code back which actually may not be necessary. You may want to toggle on and off the effects of your div in your CSS too. I think that between these two tools and toggling the effects in the div, you should be able to get your answer.